# React-router multiple component onEnter in case of auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

I am creating one app that has 2 components for a single path. Here are my routes:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} onEnter={requireEnter}>
        <Route path="/homepage" component={HomePage} />
        <Route component={MainPage} onEnter={requireAuth}>
            <Route path="/home" component={DashBoard} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

In this case I am entering into my app using the `AppContainer` component. Instead of that I want that component should be of my choice because I have a home page that will have `path="/"`.

Right now `onEnter={requireEnter}` is handling in following cases:

```
function requireEnter (nextState, replace) {
    if (nextState.location.pathname == "/") {
        if (checkLoggedIn()) {
            replace({
                pathname: '/home'
            })
        } else {
            replace({
                pathname: '/homepage'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But I want that something like this:

```
function requireEnter (nextState, replace) {
    if (nextState.location.pathname == "/") {
        if (checkLoggedIn()) {
            //component should be AppContainer and redirect to '/home'
        } else {
            //component should be home page
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Route with no component in it, had used it in another similar case:

```
<Route path="/" onEnter={requireEnter}>
  <Route path="home" component={AppContainer}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeContainer} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="homepage" component{HomePageContainer}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Then as usual:

```
function requireEnter (nextState, replace){
  if(nextState.location.pathname=="/"){
      if(checkLoggedIn()){
         replace({
              pathname: '/home'
          });
      }else{
         replace({
              pathname: '/homepage'
         });
      }
  }
}
```